# Why does Xcode still display the old object library when I'm viewing a xib?

Tags: xcode, xcode4.6

With the latest update to Xcode there is an updated object library. When I open up my project, I go to my .m file, and when I have the utilities pane open, it displays the new object library. But when I click on my .xib file to actually make changes to the UI, it goes back to the old object library, and does not show the updated objects.

I haven't been able to find any information on what might be wrong or how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that these objects that I was seeing were in fact for Mac development and not iOS development.. Silly mistake!